# Taking Larp sword in plane cabin

Tags: larp

Is it possible to take a [foam boffer sword](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B004UKQSZC/ref=sr_ph?ie=UTF8&qid=1441055012&sr=1&keywords=elven) on a plane without checking in the suitcase?

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139544/larp-weapons-on-a-plane-can-you-put-your-larp-sword-in-checked-baggage