# LARP Weapons on a Plane: Can you put your LARP sword in checked baggage?

Tags: weapons, larp, props

I'll be taking a flight soon for a Blockbuster LARP, and was wondering what would be the best means to get my latex weapon over there.

Is it possible to just check it, even if it doesn't fit inside a suitcase? Maybe wrap it in bubble wrap and put it inside a bag/box? Thoughts?

It may be too realistic looking (save for the foam/latex blade) to bring in the cabin as a carry-on.

I would appreciate advice based on experience!

Comment: Hello and welcome! You can take the [tour] to learn more about the site. Note that there is also a [travel stack exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com) where this question could probably be asked. I do think the question may be fine for this stack as well. Happy gaming!

Answer (score 5):

I have not traveled with a LARP weapon before, but I know you can travel with firearms in your checked baggage. You just have to declare it with the airline and airport security so they are aware of it.

I dont know what country you live in, but here is a link to the USA's TSA website about traveling with weapons: [Transporting Firearms & Weapons](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/transporting-firearms-and-ammunition).

Funny side note: you never have to worry about losing your checked bag if you are transporting dangerous items like weapons in them. TSA keeps a VERY close eye on those bags.

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking about US TSA regulations, I wouldn't count on it.

You cannot carry on a fencing weapon.  There are no rules for boffer swords, but considering that plastic light sabers have been taken away from toddlers in the past (though they've since ruled that [toy light sabers are in fact allowed](https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_results.aspx?search=lightsaber)) I'd err on the side of not needing to transport your LARPing sword as a carry-on item.  It has a good chance of being a big hassle at least, and possibly making you miss your flight.  Their rule on toy swords seems to be that [you should pack it in checked baggage if it looks like a real weapon](https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_results.aspx?search=foam%20toy%20sword).  The one you've posted looks enough like a real sword that I would not count on things going smoothly if you tried to travel with one.